# How to find Convergence or Divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n+\ln(n)}$ with the Limit Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could I get a step through on how to do the limit comparison test for this following problem? I am uncertain on how to break it up since I haven't encountered a problem such as this.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n+\ln(n)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \ln(n)}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. To do a limit comparison test, you want to compare $a_n$ to a new set of terms $b_n$ that *are similar to but yet simpler than* $a_n$. Well let's get rid of the $\ln(n)$ at the bottom and try out $b_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then as $a_n, b_n > 0$, we can compute:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}+\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \stackrel{\text{(L'Hôpital)}}{=} 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}} = 1 + 2\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 1
$$ So, the limit comparison test says that either both $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty b_n$ converge or they both diverge. Now what do you know about the convergence or divergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty b_n = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: May I ask, where are you getting the number 1 + etc, and 1+2 etc. in your limits?

Comment: I am primarily confused on those..

Comment: I cancelled $\sqrt{n}$ on the top and bottom of the second fraction to get $1$. There was a $\frac{1}{2}$ at the bottom of the next fraction which of course became a $2$ once you invert it.

Comment: Oh understood makes sense

Comment: wait, how did you get the 2 in the bottom?

Comment: It is not a $2$ at the bottom. It is a $\frac{1}{2}. $Did you see the small text tag saying "L'Hôpital" on one of the $=$? This allows you to "differentiate" the top $\ln(n)$ and bottom $\sqrt{n}$ of the fractions. What do you get when you differentiate $\sqrt{n}$ (thinking of it as a real function)?

Comment: Right right I missed that, my bad.

Comment: Glad to be of help.